# Android Studio kotlin Intent Intellisense not showing options as expected

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to add a second activity to an app I am creating as part of a Udemy training class and I am stuck as my Android Studio is not behaving like the instructors.
My studio version is `Chipmunk 2021.2.1`.
The problem is that when I enter `val intent = Inten` the Intellisense does not show me the construction option for
`val intent = Intent(this, MySecondActivity::class.java)` as is shown in the video (I have a screenshot but don't know how to present it here).
Also I should mention when I added the second activity I also got `FirstFragment.kt` and `SecondFragment.kt` files in my app and extra code in the `MySecondActivity.kt` file to do with Binding and NavController.
Has the Intent process been updated since Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1) Canary 11?

Comment: `does not show me the construction option for val intent = Intent(this, MySecondActivity::class.java) as is shown in the video` i find this hard to believe, how would the IDE know which activity you want to go to ?  even if i'm misunderstanding, don't focus on what your IDE is doing, focus on what you're typing and trying to do

Comment: When I entered the data I specified the Intellisense popup was displayed. There was no option in that popup for Intent(packageContext: [], class: []) where the first argument is satisfied with this and the second with the activityname with ::class.java appended.

Answer (score 0):

The developer you are following in the video must have created **Live Templates** for autocompletion of `Intent` in Android Studio. You can also create your own templates however you want to using this [guide here](https://medium.com/google-developers/writing-more-code-by-writing-less-code-with-android-studio-live-templates-244f648d17c7).

Answer (score 0):

I applied patch 1 to my studio and it is now showing what I was expecting for my Intent line of code so this problem is now solved.